# Prove that k-cube graph is a Cayley graph

Tags: group-theory, cayley-graphs

Define Cayley graph as following:

G is finite group. C $\subseteq$ G such that C does not contain identity element of G and g<sup>-1</sup> $\in$ C for all g $\in$ C. Cayley graph X(G,C) is formed with vertices V(X)=G, edges E(X)={(a,b): a,b $\in$ G, ab<sup>-1</sup> $\in$ C}.

The k-cube is the graph with vertex set {0,1}<sup>k</sup> such that any two vertices x,y  $\in$ {0,1}<sup>k</sup> are joined by an edge if and only if x and y differ in exactly one coordinate. Show that the k-cube is a Cayley graph.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Try $G=\mathbb Z_2^k$ and let $C$ be the set of $k$-tuples with $1$ in one coordinate and $0$ in every other.

Answer (score 1):

I work this out with your hint.

I have g={0,1}<sup>k</sup>. The operation in G is addtion modulo 2.

g<sup>-1</sup>=g, e={0}<sup>k</sup>

So the vertices are a,b $\in$ G.

There is edge (a,b) if a*b=e<sub>j</sub>=(x<sub>1</sub>,<sub>x2</sub>,...,x<sub>k</sub>) where x<sub>j</sub>=1, 1 $\leq$ j $\leq$ k and x<sub>i</sub>=0 for all i$\neq$j

In this case a*b<sup>-1</sup>=a*b

So C={e<sub>j</sub>, j=1,2,...,k}

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea, but you should try to clean it up a bit.